# How to use combining sequences to produce multiple codepoints

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am a linguist working on several minority languages, for which I've created my custom XKB keyboard layout together with a modified Compose table. The problem I'm having is that I can't get Ubuntu to output combining sequences if they consist of multiple codepoints and not just one. For example, here are two lines from my Compose file:

`<dead_belowdot> <t>                     :  "ṭ"  U1E6D
<dead_belowdot> <f>                     :  "f̣"  #U0066 U0323`

When I press dead_belowdot + t, I get "ṭ" but dead_belowdot + f just silently fails. On occasion, I get a warning saying "GTK+ supports to output one char only", which would seem to indicate that there is no way I could write my Compose table differently to produce "f̣". Before upgrading to zesty, these sequences did work fine. Is there anything I can do to bypass GTK's current limitation? I'm using zesty with the default desktop environment and latest updates installed.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a modified layout where a key is dedicated to type the "combining dot below" (U0323). (It's a bit surprising to me that such Compose combinations worked before zesty.)

Comment: Thanks, I had already considered combining diacritics as a workaround. For my specific situation, it's less than ideal for two reasons:1) For cases like "ṭ", where a single codepoint exists, I get U+0074 U+0323 instead of U+1E6D. Despite Unicode specifications, many programs don't treat them as equals (LibreOffice, xterm...). 2) Some of the characters I need are hard to type this way, e.g. ẓ̄ (z with dot below and macron above) or ð̣ (eth with dot below). I would rather prefer either a single key which would output them or at least an easy combining sequence (e.g. z + stroke for ẓ̄).

Comment: @Malhonen: A while ago I created a layout for a minority language in Sweden (see the bottom of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se`), where I simply added the combining ogonek. Even if most of the characters have their own code points, I decided to use combining ogonek consistently. I have not noticed a problem with LibreOffice, as you mention.

Comment: I stand corrected. The latest version of LibreOffice does treat U+0074 U+0323 and U+1E6D as equals; an earlier version I tried before did not. Gedit treats them as equals in searches but shows different glyphs for them. Shell (bash) considers them separate characters, so that if I do "grep ṭ" (0074 0323) on a file which encodes ṭ as U+1E6D, it doesn't find any matches. As most keyboard layouts seem to use precomposed codepoints, I risk losing some interoperability with people not using my custom keyboard (which is really for my own personal use, not meant for a wider public). Thanks anyways!